# QueryDsl: Select count of rows that meets the criteria

Tags: java, count, querydsl

I have 2 records in db.
Where I will do this:

```
QLoginRegistryEntry loginregistryentry = QLoginRegistryEntry.loginRegistryEntry;
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(JPA.em());
List<LoginRegistryEntry> result;
result = query.from(loginregistryentry)
              .where(loginregistryentry.inDate.startsWith(yearAndMonth))
              .list(loginregistryentry);

System.out.println(result.size());
```

**It return 2, which is correct**

When I do this:

```
QLoginRegistryEntry loginregistryentry2 = new QLoginRegistryEntry("a");
long count = query.from(loginregistryentry2).count();
System.out.println(count);
```

**It return 4, which is wrong**

What Am I doing wrong?
How should I download the count of rows that meets my criteria?

Comment: Aren't you missing the "where()" clause in your second query?

Comment: I think it dosn't matter. Without `where` part of statment it should just get all rows. Problem is that I have **two record** in that particular table. But `count()` return twice that. First query which return correct result 2, dont do `count()` at all. It gates all records, put them to list, and then count `size()` of that list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you executed the queries in isolation. Probably you just reused the query object from your first query and continued, you got a cross join and got 2 * 2 = 4 results.

Comment: As I remember, when I reuse object I am getting an error.